`TableChangedEventArgs.changeType` is always `RangeEdited`
Summary: All events delivered to an Excel.Table's onChange listener have a .changeType value of RangeEdited, when more fitting value exist in Excel.DataChangeType. No events are delivered for adding or removing rows.
Details
The code follows:
const changeHandler = async (ev: Excel.TableChangedEventArgs): Promise<void> => {
  console.log(
    `Table ${this.source} has changed %c${ev.changeType}, at ${ev.address} to ${ev.details.valueAfter}`,
    "font-weight: bold;",
    ev
  );
};

// Add the table change listener
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
  const table = context.workbook.tables.getItemOrNullObject(this.source);
  await context.sync();
  if (table.isNullObject) {
    throw new Error(`Cannot find table with id ${this.source}`);
  }

  table.onChanged.add(changeHandler);
});

The definition of Excel.DataChangeType includes RangeEdited and many others, e.g.  ColumnInserted
/**
 * Gets the change type that represents how the changed event is triggered. See `Excel.DataChangeType` for details.
 *
 * @remarks
 * [Api set: ExcelApi 1.7]
 */
changeType: Excel.DataChangeType | "Unknown" | "RangeEdited" | "RowInserted" | "RowDeleted" | "ColumnInserted" | "ColumnDeleted" | "CellInserted" | "CellDeleted";

Inserting or removing a column from the worksheet however provokes an event where .changeType is RangeEdited instead of ColumnInserted or ColumnDeleted . Indeed everything done to the table provokes a RangeEdited flavoured event, except for inserting and deleting rows, where no event is delivered.
This has been tested on macOS so far, but this feels like a bug.

Platform: Microsoft® Excel for Mac
Version 16.90 (24101387)
Darwin Mac 24.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 24.0.0: Tue Sep 24 23:37:13 PDT 2024; root:xnu-11215.1.12~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8112 arm64

